# Perl one-liner to extract groups of characters

Tags: perl

I am trying to extract a group of characters with a Perl one-liner, but I have been unsuccessful:

```
echo "hello_95_.txt" | perl -ne 's/.*([0-9]+).*/\1/'
```

Returns nothing, while I would like it to return `95`. How can I do this with Perl?

## Update:

Note that, in contrast to the suggested duplicate, I am interested  in how to do this from the *command-line*.  Surely this looks like a subtle difference, but it's not straightforward unless you already know how to effectively use Perl one-liners.

Since people are asking, eventually I want to learn to use Perl to write powerful one-liners, but most immediately I need a one-liner to extract consecutive digits from each line in a large text file.

Comment: This isn't perl, it's sed.  What are you trying to do?  Extract the integer from the filename?

Comment: Thanks @YatinSaraiya I have updated my OP. I would like to use Perl, not sed.

Comment: Eventually I would like to use this one-liner to extract consecutive digits from each line in a large text file

Comment: Thanks @YatinSaraiya You are probably right, but I am trying to switch to Perl for most text extraction/replacement tasks (learning the syntax for sophisticated queries with awk/sed/etc can be tedious)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract a number from a string in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574906/how-to-extract-a-number-from-a-string-in-perl)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
perl -pe's/\D*(\d+).*/$1/'
```

or

```
perl -nE'/\d+/&&say$&'
```

or

```
perl -nE'say/(\d+)/'
```

or

```
perl -ple's/\D//g'
```

or may be

```
perl -nE'$,=" ";say/\d+/g'
```

Comment: `$&` better written as `(\d+) && say $1`.

Comment: @squiguy Yep, it would be faster but longer.

Comment: Thanks! - What is the difference between these three options?

Comment: @user815423426 They use different approach to problem and they also will behave differently in edge cases.

Comment: Eww! The OP asked for a one-liner, not for [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com). Use some spaces. (Great answer otherwise, though, but seriously, `&&say$&`?)

Comment: For anyone else going through this hell: The single quotes apparently matter (you can't use double quotes for the command). At least on tcsh, `echo what the frack | perl -pe's/^wh(at)/$1/'` produces different output than `echo what the frack | perl -pe"s/^wh(at)/$1/"`

Answer (score 1):

Well first, you need to use the -p rather than the -n switch.

And you need to amend your regular expression, as in:

```
echo "hello_95_.txt" | perl -pe "s/^.*?([0-9]+).*$/\1/"
```

which looks for the longest non-greedy string of chars, followed by one or more digits, followed by any number of chars to the end of the line.

Note that while '\1' is acceptable as a back-reference and is more familiar to SED/AWK users, '$1' is the more up-to-date form. So, you might wish to use:

```
echo "hello_95_.txt" | perl -pe "s/^.*?([0-9]+).*$/$1/"
```

instead.

Comment: What the deal with the control-A in the RHS?

Comment: @tchrist, Ummm...there is no control-A in my answer. To what are you referring?

Comment: `$ echo "hello_95_.txt" | perl -Mwarnings=FATAL,all -pe "s/^.*?([0-9]+).*$/\1/"
Illegal variable name.
$ echo "hello_95_.txt" | perl -Mwarnings=FATAL,all -pe 's/^.*?([0-9]+).*$/\1/'
\1 better written as $1 at -e line 1.
Exit 255`

Comment: Both \1 and $1 are accepted as back-references and although $1 is the current accepted form, someone coming from AWK/SED would find \1 a little more understandable. Thanks for pointing this out though. I'll modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: "Current" accepted form? Do you realize what you are talking about by "current"? Also, your double quotes are gebroken.

Comment: @tchrist, 1. Rather than argue, please see the discussion of back-references at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html to understand why '\1' is acceptable and 2. using single or double-quotations to delimit command line arguments is operating system specific.

Comment: I beg your pardon? ***Who do you think wrote that text?*** The warning is there because you should not do it. And you still have broken double quotes. As for operating systems, you seem to have mistaken the shell for an operating system. It isn’t.

Comment: @tchrist, Ouch. That will teach me to answer comments without looking up the author first. Mea Culpa, Tom.

Comment: For the record, @tchrist is most certainly the best source of information related to Perl and I defer to his wisdom.