# How to get only the first figure of a String in Perl

Tags: perl, figure

Consider the following String:

```
AS58536:AS-V6PEERS
```

I just want to get 58536.
By now I split the string at : and the remove all nondigits.
Is there an option to look for so to say the first occurence of neighboring digits and stop at the first non-digit character?
I just am curious for a fancy one liner.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could find a simple enough regexp to match your needs by a [quick search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574906/how-to-extract-a-number-from-a-string-in-perl)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match the first sequence of digits in a string, then one of these examples might help you:

```
 echo "AS58536:AS-V6PEERS" | perl -ne '/(\d+)/ and print $1, $/;'
 perl -e '$string="AS58536:AS-V6PEERS"; $string =~ s/.*?(\d+).*/$1/; print $string,$/;'
```

I think that's what you mean by

> the first occurence of neighboring digits and stop at the first non-digit character

Comment: I'd replace the first `;` with `and`.

Comment: awesome fast answer!
as my perl skills are limited. could you apply it to something like $string="AS45345:...";  $string=~....